# book about family who travels to planet whose original inhabitants are called architects or builders

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I recently read a book and I'd like to know the author and title - it was about a girl and her politician father and two brothers who, after her mother dies suddenly, travel to a planet that has a small colony of people from earth on it, along with some original inhabitants, who have strange English names.

Earth people take a drug there to prevent them from having out of body experiences where they can see through the eyes of small lizards who roam around listening in on people's conversations.  The original inhabitants of the planet are called builders or architects, and they have mostly left the planet, but a few remain, and they are apparently affable but possibly sexually deviant.  The 13 year old girl doesn't take the drug, has some weird experiences, and has some interactions with a charismatic older man who challenges her father.  There are some other strange events and interactions among the other children.

Comment: I figured it out - it is Girl in Landscape by Jonathan Lethem.  It was a weird and interesting book.